# What game is this sprite of a blue-haired character pushing a fruit from?

Tags: game-identification

I've been given an image and the task to find which game it is from, after days of searching I'm still clueless! (apparently it's from an old Japanese arcade platformer).

[image: Blue-haired character sprite interacting with a fruit]

Comment: where do you have that image from?

Comment: Im not sure where the imaged was cropped from, this image was sent to me by a friend alone.

Comment: ([Meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10910/30863 "Why was this edit (providing a more useful title and alt content) rejected?") about a rejected edit to this question.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's "[Mr. Do!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Do!)".

The game plays very similar to Dig Dug. This screen shot and your image appear to be from the SNES version of the game.

[image]

Comment: Haha I just finally got a reply from someone...Mr Do it is indeed...

https://archive.org/details/arcade_mrdo

Comment: Funny thing... When I saw the image, without scrolling to see your answer, I thought, man that looks like some weird Dig Dug kinda guy.  I've never heard of Mr. Do, so no idea why I thought that...

Comment: @JPhi1618 You're not the only one. Exact same thought...

Comment: The screenshot shows a different version for sure. Way higher res/more colors.